# Mysql: Create a new column with values copied from another column but shifted with one row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `a` with two columns `id`, `value`, like the following:

```
+-------+-----------+
|   id  |    value  | 
+-------+-----------+
|   1   |     12    |
|   2   |     15    |
|   3   |     30    |
|   4   |     40    |
|   5   |     45    |
|   6   |     50    |
|   7   |     80    |
|   8   |     90    |
+-------+-----------+
```

I want to write a query to create a new column `shiftedValue` with value larger but closest to `value`. If the `value` is already the largest, we set `shiftedValue` as `inf`, see the last row. The desired table is as follows,

```
+-------+-----------+-------------+
|   id  |    value  | shiftedValue|
+-------+-----------+-------------+
|   1   |     12    |     15      |
|   2   |     15    |     30      |
|   3   |     30    |     40      |
|   4   |     40    |     45      |
|   5   |     45    |     50      |
|   6   |     50    |     80      |
|   7   |     80    |     90      |
|   8   |     90    |     inf     |
+-------+-----------+-------------+
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.value, IFNULL(b.value, 'inf') shiftedValue
FROM a as a LEFT JOIN a as b ON a.id = b.id - 1
```

You can add logic around this to add `inf` for when b.id is NULL.

Comment: But table `b` does not exist yet. I want to create table b.

Comment: It is the same table. Joined with itself. `a` and `b` are aliases. I know it looks weird but table `a` is not the best name. If you use real cases then it will be easier to understand.

Comment: replace `+` with `-`

Comment: Replace b.value with IFNULL(b.value, 'inf') to deal with the end case.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this is the following:

1. Create your initial two columns table that is sorted by values
2. Export the table to a csv file

   ```
   SELECT * FROM a
   INTO OUTFILE "your_csv_file.csv"
   FIELD ENCLOSED BY '"'
   TERMINATED BY ';'
   ESCAPED BY '"'
   LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
   ```
3. Edit the table with the third column (copy and past the 2nd column and change the last row's value to `inf`); you can do this easily with Excel
4. Create a new table with the 3rd column
5. Import the file to MySql

   ```
   LOAD DATA INFILE 'your_csv_file.csv' 
   INTO TABLE your_table_name 
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
   ENCLOSED BY '"'
   LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
   IGNORE 1 ROWS;
   ```

Comment: Actually, I will use this as a subquery, I think this is not suitable. Is there any pure sql way?